# What should I do to prove that my question is not similar to existing questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

I am getting  a notification that this question: [If Newton's third law is true, why do things compress?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543199/)

is similar to this question:
[If Newton's third law is true, why can we sink in sand?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409109/)

When the answers of each are related but not the same.

Comment: Conceptually, they are very similar indeed.

Comment: I understood that forces act on different bodies acc. to third law but the problem in my question is more of how the force is "transmitted"

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I forgot about my gold badge power (still getting used to it), so I accidently unilaterally reopened the question. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses cases where your question has been "closed" as a duplicate of another one.

First of all, take an honest look at your question and the proposed duplicate. Maybe they are similar enough that they should be combined, and if so, there's nothing to be done - presumably you got the information you needed, or at least you got a canonical source to check for that information.

But if you really think your question is not a duplicate, the way to show that it differs from existing questions is to mention those questions and say *exactly* what it is that you're asking which the proposed duplicate is not. The way you actually did this is fairly good:

> Edit: [If Newton's third law is true, why can we sink in sand?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409109/if-newtons-third-law-is-true-why-can-we-sink-in-sand) This question is different from this one because there the question is mainly about which bodies the forces act on according to third law while the question I asked is mainly about compression and how much force a body applies against a weight put placed on it.

(better not to say "Edit:", but that's a minor matter)